# How to get the text inserted in a tkinter text box?

Tags: python, tkinter

First, my code:

```
when = tk.Tk()
when.title("when (sec)")
when.geometry('250x120')

def WhenInput():
    print(when.get(1.0, "end"))
when = tk.Text(when, height = 10, width = 10)
when.pack()
when.mainloop()


StartIn = WhenInput
ClickDelay = 0.05
ClickRepeat = 20

mouse = Controller()

time.sleep(StartIn)

def repeat():
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    time.sleep(ClickDelay)
    mouse.release(Button.left)
for i in range(ClickRepeat):
    repeat()
```

What I want it to do is to open a text box, I insert a number for example 5, I close the window and the 5 gets put into the "StartIn" variable.

What I want my code to do when it’s ready: It opens 3 text boxes, one after another where I first input the when, then the how fast and then how much. It’s an autoclicker.

If you want you can suggest better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
StartIn = 0

when = tk.Tk()
when.title("when (sec)")
when.geometry('250x120')

def WhenInput():
    return int(when_text.get(1.0, "end-1c"))
when_text = tk.Text(when, height = 10, width = 10)
when_text.pack()

def on_closing():
    global StartIn
    StartIn = WhenInput()
    when.destroy()
    
when.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
when.mainloop()



ClickDelay = 0.05
ClickRepeat = 20

mouse = Controller()

time.sleep(StartIn)

def repeat():
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    time.sleep(ClickDelay)
    mouse.release(Button.left)
for i in range(ClickRepeat):
    repeat()
```

## Explanation

---

##### First Thing What Is Wrong In Your Code.

1. Your main root name which is `when = tk.Tk()` and the text input name is the same which is `when`.
2. You try to get the input text value after the root is destroyed.
   Which is gives you this error `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text"`.

---

##### What I Have Changed.

1. First I change the same variable name.
2. Add an event which is `protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)` which is executed when someone tries to exit or destroy the window. You notice that I pass `on_closing` as a parameter. This is because when someone tries to exit or destroy the window the `protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)` executes the `on_closing` function.
3. Inside the function, I write the first line which is `global StartIn` because I want to access the outer scope variable and want to change that (As you notice the fourth line of code is `StartIn = 0`).
4. The Second line of code inside the `on_closing` function is `StartIn = WhenInput()`. Here I call the `WhenInput` function which is return the text value in the form of `integer(int)`.
5. and, The Third line of code is `when.destroy` which is just destroy the window.

Comment: Check after 2 or 3 minute I will explain this in my post.